# Database doesn't get input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I coded a function in PHP, which posts information of upload into a database table. If someone uploads a file, I will get the DateTime of the upload and his account number but I have an issue with the file name because the user is allowed to upload more than 1 file.

```
fdatum is Datetime
fmandantnr is User Number
fdateiname is Name of the file
```

The code is like following:

datensenden_copy.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../../require.php");

$omy= new clsMYSQL();
$output = '';
$fmandantnr=$_POST['fMandnr'];
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['userfiles']['name']);$i++) {
    echo $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
    $f1name= $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
}


$query = "INSERT INTO email_hochladen 
                    (fmandantnr,fdatum,fdateiname) 
            VALUES (". $fmandantnr.",".$fdatum.",".$fdateiname.")";
echo $query;
$omy->Query($query);
?>
```

I did my research and found out I need to get this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['userfiles']['name']);$i++){
    echo $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
    $f1name= $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
}
```

Into this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO email_hochladen 
                    (fmandantnr,fdatum,fdateiname) 
          VALUES (". $fmandantnr.",".$fdatum.",".$fdateiname.")";
```

because the code cant get **fdateiname** in the SQL statement

Thank u for ur time.

Comment: Where is your `$fdateiname` and `$fdatum` is declared? You are not assigning any value to this variable so it can't be accessible and also you are using it outside of your loop so you will got only last record from loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over the $FILES array and getting the filename, but your INSERT command is OUTSIDE the loop so you only do ONE INSERT, with data from the last occurance in the loop. So simply move the insert inside the loop

> In your code `$fdatum` does not appear to be defined anywhere, I hope/assume that was just left out of the sample code you gave us, or maybe it is created in the `require.php` code

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../../require.php");

$omy= new clsMYSQL();
$output = '';
$fmandantnr=$_POST['fMandnr'];
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['userfiles']['name']);$i++) {
    echo $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];
    $f1name= $_FILES['userfiles']['name'][$i];

    $query = "INSERT INTO email_hochladen 
                    (fmandantnr,fdatum,fdateiname) 
            VALUES (". $fmandantnr.",".$fdatum.",".$fdateiname.")";

    $omy->Query($query);
}
?>
```

> Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's
>
> As I dont know anything about your `clsMYSQL();` I cannot recode this to correctly use prepared statement.

Comment: @BurnePapurn "Your script looks like it might" not might it **is** for sure atleast for blind (timing) SQL injection attacks.. `$fmandantnr=$_POST['fMandnr'];` directly used in `INSERT INTO email_hochladen 
                    (fmandantnr,fdatum,fdateiname) 
            VALUES (". $fmandantnr."` ...